# Divs completely once they are clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

I started to develop web pages. I have had some difficulty hiding div's. I provide the code through github
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/4a28050afcc3df48e40310a30a6fc25c

Comment: Please add the relevant code to your post, and explain in details, what you want your code to do, and what is does instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide / show your dom elements with `toggle()`

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/toggle/